# Apple Mach-O Linker Error with Exit Code 1

Tags: objective-c, xcode6, ios8.2

I have renamed the project from "RaceApp" to "MyDigitalDash" according to apple's docs but then suddenly it gives apple mach-o linker error with exit code 1

```
Ld /Users/Punit/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RaceApp-blcebathtrissgftkzoqtpsjwiys/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyDigitalDashTests.xctest/MyDigitalDashTests normal x86_64
cd /Users/Punit/Documents/XCode/RaceApp
export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=8.2
export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.2.sdk -L/Users/Punit/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RaceApp-blcebathtrissgftkzoqtpsjwiys/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/Punit/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RaceApp-blcebathtrissgftkzoqtpsjwiys/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.2.sdk/Developer/Library/Frameworks -F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Library/Frameworks -F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.2.sdk/Developer/Library/Frameworks -filelist /Users/Punit/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RaceApp-blcebathtrissgftkzoqtpsjwiys/Build/Intermediates/RaceApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyDigitalDashTests.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/MyDigitalDashTests.LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @loader_path/Frameworks -bundle_loader /Users/Punit/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RaceApp-blcebathtrissgftkzoqtpsjwiys/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyDigitalDash.app/MyDigitalDash -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -framework XCTest -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -mios-simulator-version-min=8.2 -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/Punit/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RaceApp-blcebathtrissgftkzoqtpsjwiys/Build/Intermediates/RaceApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyDigitalDashTests.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/MyDigitalDashTests_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/Punit/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RaceApp-blcebathtrissgftkzoqtpsjwiys/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyDigitalDashTests.xctest/MyDigitalDashTests
```

Thanks

Comment: If you expand the error, what does it say?  Some file it can't find maybe?

Comment: Have you tried cleaning the project before rebuilding it? (Cmd-Shift-K)

Comment: Yes, i have tried cleaning but still same problem.

Comment: I have renamed project. and then this happened.

Comment: @PremTomar Looks like your test cases are still having old name. If you don't have any test cases try removing them. Observe this "MyDigitalDashTests.xctest/MyDigitalDashTests"